# How to predict a specific Image (from or outside dataset) after training the KNN classifier

Tags: python, image-processing, classification, prediction

I have a simple KNN classification problem, the output of the code below is the accuracy of the classifier resulted after training the classifier and splitting the dataset into "train" and "test".

What I want my system to be like is:

- First, train the classifier using dataset;
- Upload an image from URL;
- Classify it according to the dataset.

For example, the output should be "class 1". I believe it's simple but I am pretty new to python.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)

dataset = pd.read_csv(fdes)

X = dataset.iloc[:,:20].values
y = dataset['target'].values


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.20)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)
neigh.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = neigh.predict(X_test)

y_compare = np.vstack((y_test,y_pred)).T

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
#finding accuracy from the confusion matrix.
a = cm.shape
corrPred = 0
falsePred = 0

    #prining results
for row in range(a[0]):
    for c in range(a[1]):
        if row == c:
            corrPred +=cm[row,c]
        else:
            falsePred += cm[row,c]
kernelRbfAccuracy = corrPred/(cm.sum())
print ('Accuracy of  knn : ', corrPred/(cm.sum()))
```

Comment: What is your problem, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all those steps, you can continue with:

```py
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import requests
from PIL import Image

response = requests.get(url)
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
img = np.array(img).reshape(1, -1)
output_class = neigh.predict(img)[0]
print(output_class)
```